# How can I merge two XML files into one?

Tags: ruby, perl

I need to merge two XML files. I saw this question before, but that poster wanted to simply concatenate the two files. I want to merge based on a specific child element, in this case, `id`.

I have two XML files that have the following structure:

File #1:

```
<document>
  <row>
      <id>1</id>
      <data_field1>aaaa</data_field1>
      <data_field2>bbbb</data_field2>
   </row>
</document>
```

File #2:

```
<document>
  <row>
      <id>1</id>
      <data_field3>cccc</data_field3>
   </row>
</document>
```

And I want them to be merged into File #3:

```
<document>
  <row>
      <id>1</id>
      <data_field1>aaaa</data_field1>
      <data_field2>bbbb</data_field2>
      <data_field3>cccc</data_field3>
   </row>
</document>
```

Where it uses the `id` element to join each XML entry.

Comment: I expect by using Nokogiri to read the XML files and Builder to spit out a new one, you could make this happen relatively easily.

Comment: Have you seen [XML::Merge](http://search.cpan.org/~pip/XML-Merge-1.2.565EgGd/Merge.pm) in CPAN ?

Comment: Is it possible that there will be a data field by the same name for the same ID? If so, what should happen?

Comment: @Mark Thomas, with the data I'm dealing with, I hope that's not the case, would probably make it really complex. I'm hoping that each ID appears only once in each document.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will do this, using XML::Twig

It will work with more than 2 docs, and work even if not all id's are present in both docs. It will load both files in memory though, if you want to be able to work with documents too big to fit in memory, the code will be a bit more complex. The rows will be in the same order as in the first document, then in the second one (for those that only appear in the second one).

Since it is written as a test, you can make the test case more complex, or add more tests, which would probably be a good idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;
use XML::Twig;

# normally you would read the documents from file, 
# but it's easier to write a self-contained test
my $d1='
<document>
<row>
<id>1</id>
<data_field1>aaaa</data_field1>
<data_field2>bbbb</data_field2>
</row>
</document>
';

my $d2='
<document>
<row>
<id>1</id>
<data_field3>cccc</data_field3>
</row>
</document>
';

my $merged=
'<document>
<row>
<id>1</id>
<data_field1>aaaa</data_field1>
<data_field2>bbbb</data_field2>
<data_field3>cccc</data_field3>
</row>
</document>
';
$merged=~ s{\n}{}g; # remove \n's, 
                    # if you want the result indented, look at the pretty_print option

is( merged( $d1, $d2), $merged, 'one test to rule them all');

done_testing();


sub merged
  { 
    my @docs= map { XML::Twig->new->parse( $_) } @_;

    my $merged= XML::Twig->new->parse( '<document></document>');

    my %row_id; # hash id => row_element

    foreach my $doc (@docs)
      { foreach my $row ($doc->root->children( 'row'))
          { my $eid= $row->first_child( 'id');
            my $id= $eid->text;
            # if the row hasn't been created in the merged doc, do it
            if( ! $row_id{$id})
              { $row_id{$id}= $merged->root->insert_new_elt( last_child => 'row');
                $row_id{$id}->insert_new_elt( last_child => id => $id);
              }
            # move the data fields to the end of the row
            foreach my $data_field ($eid->next_siblings) 
              { $data_field->move( last_child => $row_id{$id}); }
          }
      }
    return $merged->sprint;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Mirod, I will try that code tonight and report my results. I'm working with files that are in the 10-80 meg range, so hopefully they are not too large for what you propose.

Comment: if the files are too big, look at parsinf the 2 files in parallel, similar to what's described here: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=916069